# Cannot add to custom built linked list that has been deserialised

Tags: java, serialization, io, singly-linked-list

I have made a singly linked list with node objects which contain a data variable and a next node variable. a Customer object is stored in the data variable the customer file has a surname variable and a forename variable as follows:

```
public customer
{
String Surname;
String Forename;
get and set methods for each;
}
```

The Linked list and node class will sort in ascending order by surname (A-Z) so that George Clooney precedes Jay Gatsby. The methods used to insert an item in the linked list recursively are fine and I have run numerous tests before even trying to save the file using `ObjectOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream` or load the file using `ObjectInputStream` and `FileInputStream`.

As a result of all the research I have done, I have concluded that it is better to save the whole linked list as an object using the serializable interface on my *custom* linked list (not a standard Java list) to serialize it and save it to the file.

Now, here's my problem: I add 1 Node object with a random surname and it works fine: each time the item is added the list is deserialized from the file and loaded into a new `SinglyLinkedList` object. The new node is added and placed at the right position in the list and then this new list is passed back to the file with `ObjectOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.

I add one item and it is fine; however, if I add another, it *says* that it is fine (no errors - I have all the appropriate `try` and `catch` statements), but it doesn't actually update the list. The print method reinforces this, as it also accesses the list in the same fashion and only prints the first item (even if more are added). When I ask for the length of the list, it simply gives me the first item (e.g. returns 1).

If I were to close it and re-run it, I would once again receive this same 1 Node and nothing more. Then, if I were to add another, it would not work once again.

Here are some useful bits of info:

- The customer file, node and singly linked list classes have the necessary serializable imports and implements Serializable headers
- There are 4 separate classes, the customer file-contains the data, the Node-contains the customer file and the next node, the Singly Linked List-contains all methods for editing a list and the Main class which contains all the Scanners and Serializable Stream objects (e.g. ObjectOutputStream) and takes commands and data from the keyboard (e.g. "ADD", "PRINT")
- There are separate methods for saving and loading to the file which are used to reduce code coverage on screen- this may be the problem - I am a novice with this but here is the code.

Code for adding a node in MAIN METHOD - not recursive routine

```
CustomerFile custDat = new CustomerFile(fName,sName); 

            Node custNode = new Node(custDat, null);
            SinglyLinkedList a = loadListFromFile();
            if (a == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Creating new list");
                SinglyLinkedList newList = new SinglyLinkedList();
                newList.addRecord(custNode, null);
                a = newList;
            }
            else
            {
                a.addRecord(a.getHead(), custNode);
            }
            saveListToFile(a);
            System.out.println("File added successfully");
```

and the `loadListFromFile` method (the save list method is similar, but with output instead) has a set `fileName`:

```
private static SinglyLinkedList loadListFromFile()

{
    SinglyLinkedList lst = null;
    try
    {
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        lst = (SinglyLinkedList) is.readObject();
        is.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: is that the home asigment of the week?

Comment: Have you thought about other means of saving the data? I mean there must be a missing link somewhere, why the serialization process wont touch the second Node in your list. In cases like this I prefer going through all the trouble and use JSON or something else readable. There are enough libraries (e.g. GSON) that can transform your Java Objects into JSON and vice versa and you can verify the output directly because its plain text that you store. Or is using JSON or something else out of the question?

Comment: I could use JSON, but it is an assignment so I do need to use serialization ideally

Comment: its worth mentioning that the add method is void so that it simply adds to the list that it is applied to, not that this should make a difference, should it?

Comment: fortunately, I have solved the problem! thank you for your help but the problem was down to a failure in my logic. I running a loop that took values and added them to nodes, these nodes were being added to a list which was being declared NEW INSIDE THE LIST - ie the list could not reach the saveListToFile method and hence would not add to the list being saved in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fortunately, I have solved the problem! thank you for your help but the problem was down to a failure in my logic. I running a loop that took values and added them to nodes, these nodes were being added to a list which was being declared NEW INSIDE THE LIST - ie the list could not reach the saveListToFile method and hence would not add to the list being saved in the file